# What is a two-letter language identifier called?

Tags: terminology

A list of languages might look like so:

- English (en)
- French (fr)
- German (de)

What are the two-letter identifiers in brackets called?

Comment: What makes you think there is a specific term for that?

Comment: The ones you quote are [ISO 639-1 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) but this isn't the right group for that answer. What sort of answer are you wanting? (Please **edit the question**, don't answer in comments.)

Comment: @Lambie well i thought there might be a word for it. i guess the phrase you might be looking for is **(ISO) abbreviations**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't fit the [on-topic subjects](/help/on-topic) of Word choice and usage;
Grammar;
Etymology (history of words’ development);
Dialect differences;
Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology);
Spelling and punctuation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically, these are [**ISO 639-1 Code**](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php)s (from the [International Organization for Standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization)).

There is also a similar system but with three letters known as the **ISO 639-2**.